# How to store several distinct values under the same Java session attributes?

Tags: java, session, web, attributes

The Java web I am working on currently stores information like user name as a HttpSession attribute. The problem here is that when multiple sign on attempts made with different user names under the different tabs of the same browser, the latest user information will overwrite all previous ones. For example, sign on in tab 1 with user A, and then sign on in tab 2 with user B. At this time, when the page on tab 1 is refreshed, the user ended up as B as well, due to the fact that user information is kept in the same session attribute and affect all pages under the same session ID. So is it possible to keep distinct user information under different tabs with session attributes? If not, is there any alternative that can achieve this effect?

Comment: This is not a good idea to allowing multiple sign-on's within the same session!

Comment: Is this a behaviour you want to have or need to have? Because you should not have different login states in different tabs!

Comment: In theory, yes, one should not have multiple user sign on in the same session. I just received this as part of the requirement from my boss, and still studying its feasibility.